# How to determine which file/inode occupies a given sector

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, analysis, forensics

I received messages in `/var/log/kern.log` that indicate drive failure. The messages occured while copying my `$HOME` between drives (ext4 -> ext3):

```
[ 5733.186033] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
[ 5733.186038] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=invalid driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5733.186042] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 5733.186048] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 5733.186053] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 05 b7 2e 40 00 00 08 00
[ 5733.186064] end_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 95891008
```

The messages come in bulks, this is one of those bulks. `sdb` is the source drive.

How do I find out to which file/inode the sector belongs? I just want to know so I can recover the files in question from a backup. Anything faster than the following code plus a subsequent analysis of the output?

```
find . -type f -print \
               -exec cp \{\} /dev/null \; \
               -exec tail -n 1 /var/log/kern.log \;
```

OS: Ubuntu Oneiric.

EDIT: The command above also outputs to `stderr` the files that could not be read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rough idea would be to

1. do some calculations to find out the filesytem's block number based on the physical sector number
2. use `debugfs` testb/ncheck/icheck commands to find out if the block is in use and the name of the file(s) that are using it

There is a [bad block HOWTO over at the smartmontools project site](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/BadBlockHowto) describing the process in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Are you aware of a tool that automates this process?

Comment: No, but it should be rather easy to script something that fits the need.

Answer (score 9):

1. Find which partition the sector is in by running `fdisk -lu /dev/sdb`. Suppose it is "sdb2" which starts at sector 45612307.
2. Subtract that from 95891008 to get 50278701.
3. Next determine how many sectors per block: `tune2fs -l /dev/sdb2 | grep Block`. Suppose it is 4096.
4. Calculate the block / sector ratio: 512 bytes/sector / 4096 bytes/block = 0.125 blocks/sector.
5. Calculate the block from the sector: 50278701 * 0.125 = 6284837.625.
6. Use debugfs to find out which  is using the block. If `icheck 6284837` returns inode 12345 then run `ncheck 12345`.

Caveats: You may need to turn off journaling. This may not work with ext4.

Comment: I would add a way to check if your computations are correct, like using `stat` or  FIBMAP/FIEMAP iocalls.

Comment: On my system, `icheck` (C interface ABI/API checker) won't accept a sector number as parameter?!